# How to get value from numbered xml line using windows command batch file

Tags: xml, cmd, tags

I would need get some list of DDAT by DLFN number and put them in some csv file
For example device number (dlfn 1); device No. (dlfn 200); MAC address (dlfn 104)
will be result:
1;11536852;00:11:6D:C1:4C:3F

```
<sx_data>
<sx_r><DLFN>1</DLFN><DBEZ>Device address                </DBEZ><DDAT>1</DDAT></sx_r>
<sx_r><DLFN>2</DLFN><DBEZ>Device name                   </DBEZ><DDAT>WOS00187DA15099</DDAT></sx_r>
<sx_r><DLFN>3</DLFN><DBEZ>Department no.                </DBEZ><DDAT>1</DDAT></sx_r>
<sx_r><DLFN>4</DLFN><DBEZ>Department no. PLU accees     </DBEZ><DDAT>1</DDAT></sx_r>
<sx_r><DLFN>5</DLFN><DBEZ>Department no. EAN access     </DBEZ><DDAT>1</DDAT></sx_r>
<sx_r><DLFN>100</DLFN><DBEZ>TDHCP                         </DBEZ><DDAT>Switched on                   </DDAT></sx_r>
<sx_r><DLFN>101</DLFN><DBEZ>IP address                    </DBEZ><DDAT>10.29.1.64</DDAT></sx_r>
<sx_r><DLFN>102</DLFN><DBEZ>Subnet screen                 </DBEZ><DDAT>255.255.255.0</DDAT></sx_r>
<sx_r><DLFN>103</DLFN><DBEZ>Gateway                       </DBEZ><DDAT>10.29.1.1</DDAT></sx_r>
<sx_r><DLFN>104</DLFN><DBEZ>MAC address                   </DBEZ><DDAT>00:11:6D:C1:4C:3F</DDAT></sx_r>
<sx_r><DLFN>200</DLFN><DBEZ>Device no.                    </DBEZ><DDAT>11536852</DDAT></sx_r>
<sx_r><DLFN>1401</DLFN><DBEZ>Software package version 26</DBEZ><DDAT>2.94</DDAT></sx_r>
<sx_r><DLFN>1402</DLFN><DBEZ>Software package build 26</DBEZ><DDAT>build.8</DDAT></sx_r>
</sx_data>
```

Is it possible to use windows batch file? If it is not enough, any other easier option will be nice.
Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

Please use an XML parser (like [xidel](/questions/tagged/xidel) for instance):

```
xidel -s input.xml -e "for $x in ('1','200','104') return //sx_r[DLFN=$x]/DDAT" --output-separator=,
1,11536852,00:11:6D:C1:4C:3F

xidel -s input.xml -e "join(for $x in ('1','200','104') return //sx_r[DLFN=$x]/DDAT,',')"
1,11536852,00:11:6D:C1:4C:3F
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy for one value: filter for the correct line and read the value. Easy to expand: use the code for one line as a subroutine and call it with parameters (here the number and a variable name to store the value):

```
@echo OFF
setlocal
call :getvalue 1 var1
call :getvalue 200 var2
call :getvalue 104 var3
echo %var1%;%var2%;%var3%

goto :eof
:getvalue
for /f "tokens=9 delims=<>" %%a in ('find "<DLFN>%1</DLFN>" test.txt') do set "%2=%%a"
goto :eof
```

Result with your example data:

```
1;11536852;00:11:6D:C1:4C:3F
```

As an alternative, instead of the `call` and `echo` lines, you can use:

```
for %%a in (1,200,104) do call :getvalue %%a var%%a
echo %var1%;%var200%;%var104%
```

(note the variable names. Might be more intuitive to maintain)

Comment: if downloading and using external tools is an option, @Reino's answer is by far a safer method (because it actually parses the XML and so is much more robust to changes in XML-formatting).